# Trying to Create a table but getting error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to execute the below query

```
CREATE TABLE Jaan
(
firstname VARCHAR(256),
city VARCHAR(256),
);
```

but getting error as

```
Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Please get me know the reason why it is not getting executed

Comment: You have an extra `,` after `city VARCHAR(256)`.

Comment: you have an extra comma before the last )

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma after varchar city.

Also, unrelated, but in oracle use varchar2 over varchar.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine in my system after i removed `,` from the query

```
CREATE TABLE Jaan ( firstname VARCHAR(256), city VARCHAR(256) );
```